# Private function different results in step through and run modes

Tags: excel, runtime, step-into, vba

My code runs without errors in both step through mode and run mode. However, it is only in step through mode that I get the correct results of the calculations in the code. It is not clear where the wrong results come from in run mode.

```
    Private Function get_totals(sh As Worksheet, lastrowi As Long, rowi As Integer, n As Double, o As Integer, k As Integer, totals_sheet As Worksheet, arearange As Range)

k = 2
lastrowi = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(arearange)

    For rowi = k To lastrowi

        totals_sheet.Cells(rowi, 12).Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(rowi, 2), Cells(rowi, 4)))
        n = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(rowi, 6), Cells(rowi, 11)))
        totals_sheet.Cells(rowi, 13).Value = n / o

    Next rowi

End Function
```

I assume the problem is that it is referencing different sheets/cells when in run mode but as I set my variables outside of the function (code below) I am unsure where the problem arises. Anyone with fresh eyes able to spot the cause of error?

```
  For Each sh In Sheets(Array("pipe_totals", "node_totals")) 'needs expanding once the calcs sheets are in

If sh.Name = "pipe_totals" Then
    Set sh1 = Sheets("pipe_diam_calcs")
    Set totals_sheet = Sheets("pipe_totals") 'will change for each asset group node/wps/reservoir/address
    Set arearange = totals_sheet.Columns("A:A") ' will change for node/wps/reservoir/address
    Set dmalist = sh1.Columns("c:c")
    o = 6

        ElseIf sh.Name = "node_totals" Then
            Set sh1 = Sheets("node_z_calcs")
            Set totals_sheet = Sheets("node_totals") 'will change for each asset group node/wps/reservoir/address
            Set arearange = totals_sheet.Columns("A:A") ' will change for node/wps/reservoir/address
            Set dmalist = sh1.Columns("c:c")
            o = 2

End If

Call getdma_list(dmalist, arearange)
Call loop_weight_tot(sh, totals_sheet, arearange, sh2, rowi, row, rowW, dma_string, k, col, colNum, colNum_new)

Call get_totals(sh, lastrowi, rowi, n, o, k, totals_sheet, arearange) 'need to be defined outside of function???

Next sh

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: What do `loop_weight_tot` and `getdma_list ` do?  Also, your function doesn't return anything . You can use that as a sub.

Comment: @peege 'getdma_ list' gets a range of values from another sheet and places them on the totals sheet in column A. 'loop_weight_tot' uses match to find values relating to the list obtained in 'getdma_list'. What is the benefit of using it as a sub rather than a function? Cheers

Comment: Subs perform operations and functions can return values.  Functions can perform operations also, but what separates them is the added functionality of the return.

Comment: If you put break points in and run, do the calculations still come out wrong? As opposed to stepping through.  And do you use the locals window?

Comment: @peege with break points I get the same result as with running the code - i.e. the wrong results. I didn't know about the locals window so I will check it out, looks incredibly useful :)

Comment: Yes.  Here's what I'd do.  Insert break points around just the calls to the functions.  Then examine the Locals Window.  See where the values deviate from your expectations. It's a good thing it doesn't work with the break points.  That will help.

Comment: Start by qualifying all of your `Range()` and `Cells()` with worksheet references. e.g.  `sheetRef.Range(sheetRef.Cells(...), sheetRef.Cells(...))` and not just `Range(Cells(...), Cells(...))`   If you don't do this, they will default to the `ActiveSheet` and that makes results unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, I previously tried to qualify them but kept getting runtime errors, 'n = Application.Sum(totals_sheet.Range(Cells(rowi, 6), totals_sheet.Cells(rowi, 11)))' returns range of class of object _worksheet failed.

Comment: @TimWilliams I used a workaround, by activating `totals_sheet` and using `With Activesheet`. It returns the desired results but I suspect it is inelegant/slow!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to activate a sheet (and you should always try to avoid writing code which relies on a specific sheet being active)

Eg:

```
With totals_sheet
    .Cells(2, 15).Value = Application.Sum( _
                         .Range(.Cells(2, 12), .Cells(lastrowi, 12)))
    .Cells(2, 16).Value = Application.Average( _
                         .Range(.Cells(2, 13), .Cells(lastrowi, 13)))
End With
```

Comment: @TimWillams this makes sense but  get the same runtime error.

Comment: If that last block in your posted answer works, then this should too, since it's functionally the same (but without relying on the sheet being active)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an inelegant solution, as suspected the problem seemed to be that the references to cells/ranges were unqualified but when I attempted to qualify them with `Application.Sum(totals_sheet.Range(Cells(rowi, 6), totals_sheet.Cells(rowi, 11)))` I got runtime error range of class of object _worksheet failed.

My very inelegant solution was to activate the `totals_sheet`

```
Private Function get_totals(sh As Worksheet, lastrowi As Long, rowi As Integer, n As Double, o As Integer, k As Integer, totals_sheet As Worksheet, arearange As Range)

k = 2
lastrowi = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(arearange)

    For rowi = k To lastrowi

        totals_sheet.Activate 'to prevent active sheet returning unpredictable results

            With ActiveSheet
            totals_sheet.Cells(rowi, 12).Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(rowi, 2), Cells(rowi, 4)))
            n = Application.Sum(totals_sheet.Range(Cells(rowi, 6), totals_sheet.Cells(rowi, 11)))

            totals_sheet.Cells(rowi, 13).Value = n / o
            End With


    Next rowi

'get total mains/weight for the model
    totals_sheet.Activate
        With ActiveSheet
            totals_sheet.Cells(2, 15).Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(lastrowi, 12)))
            totals_sheet.Cells(2, 16).Value = Application.Average(Range(Cells(2, 13), Cells(lastrowi, 13)))
        End With

End Function
```

I welcome any feedback/criticism on how to improve this to help me develop my VBA skills which are a bit lacking at present!

Cheers

Comment: This will work, but is not robust for the reason outlined in my comment above.  You can fix it be qualifying all of your Range and Cells calls.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes I agree it's not robust but I can't seem to qualify the ranges within `application.sum` or `application.average` without getting runtime errors. Any idea why this is the case?